# Google App-engine installation issue in Eclipse Luna on Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am installing the google app-engine plugin for eclipse in eclipse version luna.Installation proceeds till 12% and then fails with the following error.

> No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.6.1.20150625-2337
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.6.1.20150625-2338
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.6.1.20150625-2338
>   No repository found containing:

I came across some posts related to this problem and have tried unchecking the option "Contact all update sites during install".But the error is still there.
I have attempted installation several times and on different days.Still can't get the errors out of the way.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are the plugins for Eclipse Maven integration. Release 1.6.1 is the very latest release which can be found at `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases`.

I am not sure if this release is suitable for Luna, are you sure you are installing the version of the engine for Luna as described [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.4)?

Comment: I tried installing the Maven Integration Plugins(both versions 1.6 and 1.5).But the attempt failed with "No repository found containing" errors.The version I am installing for Luna is as per the instructions given at the linked wesite(4.4).